# How to restrict database ports on a cloud host?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, port, database

I want to set up a node.js/mongoDB app on Digital Ocean. It's not going to see a ton of traffic, so just one virtual machine instance is plenty.

When mongodb starts up, it attaches to default port 27017. Does this mean that the port is also available to anyone who hits myip:27017 or myserver.com:27017?

How do I make the database only accessible to my app?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no advanced/customized firewall settings:

If Mongodb is bound to 127.0.0.1 it will only be accessible from that machine or the local network.

If it is bound to 0.0.0.0 or an actual network interface connected to your server, it will be on the open internet.

Answer (score 0):

Default config of mongodb installation on Ubuntu would bind 27017 to 127.0.0.1.

This means only 127.0.0.1 can access the port.

Check `mongodb.conf`, and see if `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` exists.

If there is not, anyone who can access your machine can access your mongodb. It's dangerous.